# Select unique rows with latest timestamp without changing original order

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct

Say I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, name, registration_date
FROM users 
ORDER BY registration_date DESC nulls last;
```

This results in:

```
id     name           registration_date
-----------------------------------------------
1a     John Doe       2020-08-21 17:00:41+0000
2a     Joe Darwin     2020-07-21 20:14:10+0000
3a     Jim Lee        2020-07-15 16:14:10+0000
```

I have another table `activity` where there are multiple records for each user when they were logging in:

For example

```
id   user_id   last_active
----------------------------------------
1.   1a        2021-05-18 16:14:01+0000
2.   1a        2021-05-17 10:14:01+0000
3.   2a        2021-05-21 12:14:01+0000
4.   2a        2021-05-19 12:14:01+0000
5.   3a        2021-04-17 00:00:01+0000 
6.   3a        2021-03-01 00:00:01+0000
```

I need to do a join on this table to select the most recent `last_active` timestamp for each user. I can do it with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(u.id) u.id, u.name, u.registration_date, a.last_active
FROM users
LEFT JOIN activity a ON u.id = a.user_id
ORDER BY u.id, registration_date DESC nulls last;
```

However, this changes the original order of the original result. I don't want to order by `u.id` -- I need the query to be ordered by `registration_date` and simply add another column for each row with the most recent `last_active` date. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried: `SELECT distinct on(u.id, registration_date) ... order by registration_date desc nulls last`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moin,

I had same problem times ago, i saved it by using row number over.
So in the first step you will create a unique list with the latest login and second you can join it.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id order by last_active desc) oNR, 
 User_ID,
 last_Active
FROM activity
)s 
WHERE s.oNR = 1
```

---

Now you can join this to your user

```
SELECT distinct on(u.id) u.id, u.name, u.registration_date, a.last_active
FROM users
left join 
(
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id order by last_active desc) oNR, 
 User_ID,
 last_Active
FROM activity
)s 
WHERE s.oNR = 1 

)


a
on u.id = a.user_id
order by u.id, registration_date desc nulls last;
```

sorry for the bad formatting.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort it as required by the DISTINCT ON, then re-sort it as required by the desired output order.  You will need to add a subquery to add another ORDER BY.

```
select * from (
  SELECT distinct on(u.id) u.id, u.name, u.registration_date, a.last_active
  FROM users
  left join activity a
  on u.id = a.user_id
  order by u.id, a.last_active desc nulls last
) foo order by registration_date desc nulls last;
```